# Display each sql db row in a single php page

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display each single row from my db as a separated unique page, so when I click on the row link (which I don't even know what it is until now) it directs me to a new page with the content of this row or some of the content as I desire..

So I created a new php file, and inserted this code but it doesn't work after all.

```
include "db_connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT Joke_question, Joke_answer FROM jokes_table WHERE JokeID = '". $_GET['JokeID']."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()

   echo $row["Joke_question"];

?>
```

Tried to include `?id=` into the url to see if I can actually access a row in a unique page, but still doesn't work.

I am a beginner, so I hope the answer will be simple enough for me to understand.

I want to know what should I do to generate a page for each row I have?

Edit:

PROBLEM SOLVED BY CHANGING THE CODE INTO THIS (BUT i have another issue):

```
$id = $_GET['JokeID'];

$sql = "SELECT Joke_question FROM jokes_table WHERE JokeID = '". $id."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Joke_question"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

But sadly i have another problem..

I wanna display a URL for each row in my database on my main page, but i dont wanna do this manually one by one, i want it to be generated dynamically through a loop.

What im using on my main page:

```
<a href="single_joke.php?JokeID=1">click</a>
<a href="single_joke.php?JokeID=2">click</a>
<a href="single_joke.php?JokeID=3">click</a>
```

I want to loop the process.

EDIT(SOLVED):

Updated Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jokes_table";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$breaking_space = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $breaking_space[]='<a href="single_joke.php?JokeID='. $row['JokeID'].'">'.$row['Joke_question'].'</a>';
            
}
echo implode('<br/> ', $breaking_space);
```

Comment: If you use `?id=` then you have to use `$_GET['id']`, not `$_GET['JokeID']`

Comment: Or you can use `?JokeID=` and then it will work with the code you posted.

Comment: Your code is also open to SQL-injection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: tried ?JokeID= , still doesnt work..

Comment: Enable error reporting and see if there are any warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: Show how you create your link to the new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all the rows on the page and then display it as links using the fetch_assoc function

```
$sql = "SELECT JokeId FROM jokes_table";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a href='single_joke.php?JokeID=".$row['JokeId']."'>click</a>";
}
```

you can also use `SELECT * FROM jokes_table`if you want other columns from the database table.

this will get all the rows of the table and display it as a link that will go to their respective page.